# MySQL: Returning value from chain query alongside original return value

Tags: mysql

I am designing a query to retrieve two fields that are related to each other by a third table:

```
    select F.Food_name
    from FoodType as F
    where F.Food_ID in (
       select U.Food_ID
       from Used_Ingredients as U
       where RecipeID = U.Recipe_ID
);
```

I would also like to return U.Food_ID alongside F.Food_name. How should I go about this?

Comment: ??f.food_id must be the same as u.food_id? sample data and expected outcome as text  would help clarify.